# A simple data class based on an existing collection (Scala)

Tags: scala

I'm fairly new to Scala and I would like to learn it properly. My current task is to create a type to represent a heap, as seen in interpreters: a mapping from addresses in memory to values stored there.

A heap of that kind is very much like Map, but I would like to hide implementation details and only expose the interface consisting of a few methods, which in pseudo code would be:

```
* update :: address value -> Heap
* free :: address -> Heap
* alloc :: value -> (Heap, Address)
* addresses :: () -> Set[Address]
* lookup :: address -> [Value]
```

Here is what I came up with:

```
trait Heap[T] {

  def update(address: Address, value: T): Heap[T]

  def free(address: Address): Heap[T]

  def alloc(value: T): (Heap[T], Address)

  def addresses(): Set[Address]

  def lookup(address: Address): Option[T]
}

private case class HeapImpl[T](map: Map[Address, T]) extends Heap[T] {
  override def update(address: Address, value: T): Heap[T] = HeapImpl[T](map.updated(address, value))

  override def free(address: Address): Heap[T] = HeapImpl[T](map.removed(address))

  override def alloc(value: T): (Heap[T], Address) = {
    val nextFreeAddress = addresses().maxOption.getOrElse(0) + 1
    (HeapImpl(map.updated(nextFreeAddress, value)), nextFreeAddress)
  }

  override def addresses(): Set[Address] = map.keys.toSet

  override def lookup(address: Address): Option[T] = map.get(address)
}

object Heap {
  def apply[T](): Heap[T] = HeapImpl(Map())
}
```

I would like to know if this is proper idiomatic Scala or should I approach it differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code, as posted, doesn't compile because there is no definition for the `Address` type. However, given the code for `nextFreeAddress` in the `alloc()` method, it's pretty obvious that `Address` can only be type `Int`, so that's easy to fix.

Also, `HeapImpl` is `private` to ... what? A surrounding `object` I assume, but that's also missing from the posted code so it's a bit unclear. You say you "would like to hide implementation details," which is a good thing, but I don't know that a private implementation class is significantly more hidden than having private members of a public class. Is the implementation class separate because you envision multiple different implementations available to the end user?

It's a bit unusual to have a factory method that takes no parameters except for a type parameter. It wouldn't be difficult to enhance the "constructor" to take optional initial values.

```
object Heap {
  def apply[T](ts:T*): Heap[T] = HeapImpl(ts.indices.map(x => x -> ts(x)).toMap)
}
```

Then you can have it both ways:

```
Heap[Char]()           //res0: Heap[Char] = HeapImpl(Map())
Heap(3L, 5L, 12L, 2L)  //res1: Heap[Long] = HeapImpl(Map(0 -> 3, 1 -> 5, 2 -> 12, 3 -> 2))
```

(Notice that the REPL has leaked a bit of your implementation detail.)

At first I was confused by the term `Heap`. Then I re-read the posting and realized that this isn't a [heap data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) but is, instead, a chunk of memory for dynamic allocation and requiring [memory management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management).

But your code doesn't actually do any of the things that makes a real heap challenging/interesting: dynamic allocation for heterogeneous data, handle fragmentation, etc. It sort of *pretends* to be a heap, but not very convincingly (your `alloc()` doesn't really act like `malloc()`, `calloc()`, or `realloc()`). It's just a thin wrapper around a highly restricted [associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array).

So, while I find little to fault in the code, I can't see where it serves much purpose.

Comment: "Also, HeapImpl is private to ... what? A surrounding object I assume" -- The package. This is what I have at the top level in a file, the only thing missing was a package declaration. 

Anyway, thanks! Good point that I might have as well have a class with public methods instead of a trait (since I don't expect alternative implementations).